# Openpyxl - Offset using cell value from above

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to iterate down a column and if I find an empty cell, use the value from the cell above.

I want to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

I'm using offset but I can only list the values from below the current cell.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl

wb = load_workbook("original-workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
    if row[0].value and row[0].value.startswith("Microsoft"):
        print("Ocupado!")
    else:
        row[0].value = row[0].offset(row=1, column=0).value

wb.save("new-improved-workbook.xlsx")
```

Is there an alternative?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You were able to find if a cell had content or not. All you need to do is save that content into a variable so when a cell is empty you put the saved value in it.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("original-workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
    if row[0].value and row[0].value.startswith("Microsoft"):
        saved_value = row[0].value
        print("Ocupado!")
    else:
        row[0].value = saved_value

wb.save("new-improved-workbook.xlsx")
```

Comment: Perfect - cheers mate!